# How to clear bluetooth cache when it is disabled?

Tags: settings, bluetooth, cache

I'm trying to follow online guides like [this](https://support.hestancue.com/en/support/solutions/articles/19000093815-android-how-to-clear-the-app-and-bluetooth-cache-) or [this](https://www.airdroid.com/remote-control/fix-bluetooth-not-working-android-problem/) to clear the bluetooth storage on my Pixel 5a.

1. Settings > Apps > All > Triple Dots > Show System > Bluetooth
2. Storage & Cache
3. I want to tap "Clear cache" but the button is disabled:

[image: Clear cache button is disabled]

How can I clear the Bluetooth settings?

---

The reason I'm trying this is I'm having problems with pairing my Pixel Buds, but only from *my* phone. I can successfully pair them from my macbook, and can set them up from another Pixel. But on my phone during Set Up it runs for a while, then fails with the error message:

> Couldn't connect
> Try manually pairing to the device by going to Settings

And the Pixel Buds have been renamed to "Carl's Pixel Buds" but they're not connected. Trying to connect by tapping on the entry in bluetooth, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this option is disabled. The closest option I can find is

1. Settings > System > Reset options
2. Reset Wi-fi, mobile & Bluetooth

*This is a big hammer! Thanks to @acejavelin for more context:*

> It is probably worth stating that this does a LOT more than just reset Bluetooth settings... All saved WiFi passwords, any custom APN settings, Hotspot settings, VPN settings, Data Saver settings, etc... will all be returned to factory defaults. Clearing data on Bluetooth is only clearing the driver cache, not the actual settings, this they would be automatically regenerated with no effect.

This didn't change the `kB` for either User data or Cache, but it did remove my existing paired devices.

---

After doing this reset then rebooting my phone, my Pixel Buds successfully paired!

Comment: It is probably worth stating that this does a LOT more than just reset Bluetooth settings... All saved WiFi passwords, any custom APN settings, Hotspot settings, VPN settings, Data Saver settings, etc... will all be returned to factory defaults. Clearing data on Bluetooth is only clearing the driver cache, not the actual settings, this they would be automatically regenerated with no effect.

Comment: This does nothing to clear the blutooth cache is there a way to do it via adb maybe?